# How to plot Matplotlib chart which takesvalues from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my dataframe

```
        Order  Time  Profit
0       1   106     NaN
1       1   111  -296.0
2       2    14     NaN
3       2    16  -296.0
4       3    62     NaN
..    ...   ...     ...
335   106    32  -297.6
336   107    44     NaN
337   107    44   138.0
338   108    58     NaN
339   108    63  -303.4
```

So the way I want it to work is plot a chart where X is the time, Y is the absolute price(positive or negative) so we need to have 2 bars. Now, the time should not be from the same row, but from the first row with the same order number.
For ex. The -296.0 would be under time 106, not 111 because 106 was the first under Order nr.1. How would we do something like that?

This is my code so far:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Order','Time','Profit']).astype(str)

#turns time column into hours of week
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: findHourOfWeek(x))
df['Profit'] = df['Profit'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure we see in the sample of your data holds over the entire data set, i.e. there is only one Profit value per Order, you can do it like this: Group the DataFrame by Order, and aggregate by taking the minimum:

```py
df_grouped = df.groupby(by='Order').min()
```

resulting in this DataFrame:

```py
       Time  Profit
Order       
1      106   -296.0
2       14   -296.0
3       62      NaN
...
106     32   -297.6
107     44    138.0
108     58  -303.4
```

Then you can sort by Time and do the plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_grouped.sort_values(by='Time', inplace=True)
plt.plot(df_grouped['Time'], df_grouped['Profit'])
```

Comment: When I type df.groupby....

I get this https://prnt.sc/rzd47e

Comment: Ah, that's because you have cast `Order` as string when you created `df`. Don't do that. In general, pandas is pretty good at figuring out the variable types by itself. `Order` should clearly be integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you rather want to rely on position in the data table you can also do this:

```
plot_df = pd.DataFrame()
plot_df["Order"] = df.Order.unique()
plot_df["Profit"] = list(df.groupby("Order").nth(-1)["Profit"])
plot_df["Time"] = list(df.groupby("Order").nth(0)["Time"])
```

However, if you want min value for time you'd better use solution provided by Arne since it would be more safe and correct (provided that you only have one profit value for each order number).